# Make div fill remaining width with list-style-position: inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get another div *fill the remaining space* in the numerical li with **list-style-position: inside** but I can't seem to get it working.

Although I could use **list-style-position: outside** and add spacing because it overlaps other elements on the page, I would much prefer positioning it inside if that is possible. I plan on the list going past 100 items.

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
}

.myClass {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%; /* fill remaining space in the li */
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="myClass"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove display:inline-block or set it back to block if you want to have a single element per line ... else clarify the question with more html examples ... of what could be in that li ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the `li`, use css `counter` on a pseudo element for the number, then set `.myClass` to `flex-grow: 1`

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: section;       
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}

.myClass {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="myClass"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome Michael. Thanks for the answer and quick response. I didn't think about using counter-increment and content. Learned something new!

Comment: @AndyHuynh you bet, glad it helped.